# Cannot set ylim for sklearn partial dependence plot

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am following [this example on sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_partial_dependence_visualization_api.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-partial-dependence-visualization-api-py)

I want to change the limits of y axis so I can visually compare results from different models.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay

diabetes = load_diabetes()
X = pd.DataFrame(diabetes.data, columns=diabetes.feature_names)
y = diabetes.target

tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()
tree.fit(X, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.set_ylim(50,300)
tree_disp = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(tree, X, ["age", "bmi"], ax=ax)
```

However, it seems that *ax.set_ylim* get ignored no matter what I specify. On the other hand, *ax.set_title* given in example works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PartialDependenceDisplay` have an `axes_` attribute that represents both matplotlib's axes of the figure.

You can modify them as follow:

```
tree_disp = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(tree, X, ["age", "bmi"], ax=ax)
tree_disp.axes_[0][0].set_ylim(50,300)
tree_disp.axes_[0][1].set_ylim(50,300)
```

This will output the following plot:

[image]